Filter nodes in quasar tree with lazy loading
How can I filter nodes in an quasar tree component when I have lazy child nodes ?
The problem is that when I have an lazy loading system, I need to open the entire tree in order to filter, ortherwise closed nodes will not appear in my filter.

are you able to do this? there is documentation in quasar.dev about this. you can follow it. if not you can show what code you have and we will help you fix it

@MikaelTenshio I'm trying a similar thing right now, can you point me to the docs where it mentions the lazy + filtering? I see the sections on lazy and filtering, but not how to use them together. Thanks!

@Marty  https://quasar.dev/vue-components/tree#custom-filter-method

@MikaelTenshio hey sorry for the delay in getting back to you, can you point out where it talks about lazy loading + filtering? I see filtering and then I see lazy loading, but not how they are used together. Thanks!
PS: My work around now is to trigger my lazy loading logic manually when my custom filter is called, but that's not ideal because the lazy load internal state that Quasar uses to track if a node has been loaded is bypassed, meaning the tree will never load some nodes. My work around for that is to lazy load all possible adjacent nodes as well, but that's not great.
